# Wobble the y(up) axis of a circle

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I wrote a script that moves a game object(w/ trail render) in a circular motion via the sin/cos functions

```
x = center.x + Mathf.Sin(t) * r;
z = center.z + Mathf.Cos(t) * r;
position = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
```

i would like to know how to tweak the y axis to wobble/tilt it like a spinning coin as it slows down.

what kind of math would i apply to do that? I applied x to y which tilts it, but it remains that way instead of moving its high/low ends around

Comment: It's unclear to me here what motion you want. The code you've shown is modifying position, but it sounds like you're describing a kind of rotation. Can you show us a more concrete example of what you're trying to do and how your results so far differ from what you want?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm pretty sure he wants the motion done by the droids at 5:10 in [this video](https://youtu.be/WJHZFcAAUiE), but in 3d. I don't have the time right now to answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to lift one side up. You can do this pretty easily by just setting the y axis to the sine of t:

```
x = center.x + Mathf.Sin(t) * r;
y = Mathf.Sin(t) * height;  // Height is the maximum height the coin reaches
z = center.z + Mathf.Cos(t) * r;
position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

However, this will make the coin stay in place as you seem to have noticed. To make the high end move around, add the current time (not the same as `t`) to `t`. You can use `Time.time` in Unity:

```
x = center.x + Mathf.Sin(t) * r;
y = Mathf.Sin(t + Time.time) * height;  // Height is the maximum height the coin reaches
z = center.z + Mathf.Cos(t) * r;
position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

2D example in JavaScript:

```js
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let time = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  for (let t = 0; t < 30; t++) {
    let x = Math.sin(t / 15 * Math.PI);
    let y = Math.sin(t / 15 * Math.PI + Date.now() / 1000 * 3);
    ctx.fillRect(x * 150 + 250, y * 75 + 250, 10, 10);
  }

  time += 0.016;
}, 16);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```